# set cookie header flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

While trying to add headers "Cookie" for a login process in flutter web, I keep getting "refused to set unsafe header cookie flutter" error. I tried every way. If I cannot add this token to the cookie, I cannot login. It works on mobile, but not on the web.